# pipeline function in MongoDB, how to make the join

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am looking at a query in MongoDB.

Essentially, I want to join records, but only when the records in collection `mongo2` meet certain conditions (those in the and statement).

I have 2 questions about this

1. Where can I put the local and foreign field setting. It says I cannot define them when using pipeline.
2. Its says that my GT and LT statements are wrong. They work in single find statements, but I am getting the error

> Expression $gt takes exactly 2 arguments. 1 were passed in.

Any help will be massivel appreciated :)

Thanks guys

```
   db.mongo.aggregate([
     { $lookup:
         {
           from: "mongo2", 
           pipeline: [
                { $match:
                    { $expr:
                        { 
                          $and:[{Age : {$gt:50}}, {Age : {$lt:100}}]       
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "filters"
            }
     }
    ])
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to access fields coming from `mongo` collection inside of `pipeline` is to define them as variables using `let` statement. For instance:

```
db.mongo.aggregate([
    { 
        $lookup: {
            from: "mongo2",
            let: { "mongo_collection_id": "$_id" },
            pipeline: [
                { 
                    $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$$mongo_collection_id", "$_id" ] } }
                }
            ],
            as: "filters"
        }
    }
])
```

Please note that you need double dollar sign (`$$`) to refer to that variable within pipeline. Single dollar references fields from `mongo2` collection documents.

Answering second question: there are two `$gt` and `$lt` pairs in MongoDB (which might be confusing). Since you probably have to use `$expr` the only way is to use [$gt (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/) so the syntax is a bit different:

```
{ $expr:
    { 
        $and:[{ $gt: [ "$Age", 50 ] }, { $lt: [ "$Age", 100 ] }]       
    }
}
```